# Making my site login "mirror" Facebook login

Tags: facebook

I've noticed that Huffington Post does this: if you log out of there, it **forces** you to log out of Facebook as well, and if you log in on Facebook and go back to Huffington Post, it **automatically** logs you in there as well. Is this a straightforward use of the FB Connect API that I just haven't noticed, or is there some trick?

Comment: I think I saw this (or something very similar) answered sometime last week... Can't find it though...

Comment: "Is this a straightforward use of the FB Connect API"?  Yes.  This is how connect works.  In fact, there's no other way to use connect.

Comment: There certainly is another way to use Connect. For example, on http://www.shredunion.com (my site), you can already be logged into Facebook, but will not be logged in to shredunion.com unless you actually click the Connect button.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of [fb:login-button](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:login-button), which is part of Facebook-connect. When users login with this feature, it links their facebook account with your website.

Using the [connect wizard](http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?connect_wizard), you can customize what your button does, and the [documentation](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:login-button) explains how to manually add extra features to the button.

Here is an example on how to use it:

```
<fb:login-button v="2"><fb:intl>Connect with Facebook</fb:intl></fb:login-button>
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already have Connect working. My question is about the automatic behavior, where you get logged into the 3rd-party site without doing anything.